# PHP function to flat a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [Banana] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 57
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 58
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 59
                )
        )
)
```

Does PHP have a magic function to return something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Banana] => 57,58,59
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you read the article marked as duplicate.  However, in this case, `$arr['Banana'] = implode(',', array_column($arr['Banana'], 0));` should probably do it

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize any magic function like this but you can easily achieve it using the following:

```php
function magicTrick($array) {
    return array_combine(array_keys($array), array_map(function($values) {
        return implode(',', array_map(function($value) {
            return $value[0];
        }, $values));
    }, $array));
}
```

How it works:

1. Iterates through the each entry to merge the values into string using the `implode` function,
2. combine the results with the initial array keys using the `array_combine` function.

Answer (score 0):

The [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function is used to join elements of an array with a delimiter in between them.

In your case, you want to iterate over the elements of the outer array and replace their contents with a string of comma separated values, correct?

```php
foreach ($your_array as &$value) {
  $value = implode(',', array_map(fn($subvalue) => implode(',', $subvalue), $value));
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to first flatten the sub-arrays.

```php
foreach ($your_array as &$value) {
  $flattened_array = [];
  array_walk_recursive(function ($el) use (&$flattened_array) {
      $flattened_array[] = $el;
    }, $value); 
  $value = implode(',', $flattened_array);
}
```

Comment: Both your solutions try to implode the full arrays instead of array values

Comment: @DanielStasiak Fair point. I didn't notice he had a two-dimensional array inside the outer fruit array. I'll update the answer.